# How do I update the children in a one-to-many relationship in Vapor 4/FluentKit?

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

I've combed through the docs [here](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/fluent/relations/#parent) and I can't quite figure out how to update the relationship and the model (e.g., there are changes to the relation and a change to a property). It appears that the "childrenArray" in ModelA is empty after decoding, however, I can't be sure because I get this error when attempting to print the value:

> Fatal error: Children relation not eager loaded, use $ prefix to access

My parent model:

```
final class ModelA: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "model_a"
    
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "name")
    var name: String
    
    // MARK: - RELATIONS
    
    @Children(for: \.$modelA)
    var childrenArray: [ModelB]

    init() { }

    init(id: UUID? = nil, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

The model for the children:

```
final class ModelB: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "model_b"

    // MARK: - Properties
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "command")
    var command: String
    
    // MARK: - Relations
    
    @Parent(key: "model_a_id")
    var modelA: ModelA
}
```

My update function:

```
func update(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<ModelA> {
        guard let id = req.parameters.get("id", as: UUID.self) else {
            throw Abort(.internalServerError)
        }
        
        let updatedModelA = try req.content.decode(ModelA.self)
        return ModelA.find(id, on: req.db)
            .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
            .flatMap { modelA in
                modelA.$childrenArray.create(updatedModelA.childrenArray, on: req.db)
                return modelA.update(on: req.db).map { modelA }
            }
    }
```

For reference, the Postman `POST` request looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "<ModelA's UUID>",
    "name": "ModelA Name",
    "childrenArray": [{
        "id": "{{$randomUUID}}" ,
        "command": ""
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete the 'eager load', you need to include a `with` on the parent query. You can't do this with a `find` so you will need to change your query to:

```swift
ModelA.query(on: req.db)
    .filter(\.$id == id)
    .with(\.$childrenArray)
    .first()
    .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
    .flatMap { modelA in
        // can access children now
        return modelA.update(on: req.db).map { modelA }
    }
```

I assume you want this line to create children in ModelB:

```swift
modelA.$childrenArray.create(updatedModelA.childrenArray, on: req.db)
```

It won't. You'll need to create a new instance of `ModelB`, initialise the parent property and then call `create`.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I can do that. Looks like there's also a way to save an array of models I can utilize in this instance too here https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/fluent/model/#create. 
One last question though which I'll need to know in order to do what you mentioned - I'm still getting the "eager load" error when accessing the children after this line:
`let updatedModelA = try req.content.decode(ModelA.self)` It's just decoding the request, so there is no db query at this juncture. How can I access the `childrenArray` of this object? Do I have to decode to a data model that doesn't extend `Model`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment till just now. Use a dedicated Decodable structure with just the fields you want from the request instead of the ModelA itself.